# Solving an equation for a space dependent variable

Tags: equation-solving

How can I find $f(x)$ in the interval $(x_1,x_2)$? I know the values of the coefficients as $c=0.5$, $b=1.1$ and $(x_1,x_2)=(-10,10)$.

```
f[x] == c Cos[2 f[x]] + b x
```

I want to find $f(x)$ and plot $\sin(f(x))$ in the interval $(x_1,x_2)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

c = 1/2;
b = 11/10;

{x1, x2} = {-10, 10};

eqn = f[x] == c Cos[2 f[x]] + b x;

f[x_] = f[x] /. 
   DSolve[{D[eqn, x], f[0] == (f0 /.
         Solve[(eqn /. x -> 0 /. f[0] -> f0), f0,
           Reals][[1]])}, f[x], {x, x1, x2}][[1]] //
  FullSimplify

(* InverseFunction[-(1/2) Cos[2 #1] + #1 &][(11 x)/10] *)

Plot[f[x], {x, x1, x2}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Sin[f[x]], {x, x1, x2}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1, nice and smooth.

Answer (score 3):

This kind of problem can be solved with `FixedPoint` iteration. I've used 500 iterations max:

```
c = 1/2.;
b = 1.1;
g[x_, y_] := c Cos[2 y] + b*x
fp[x_] := FixedPoint[g[x, #] &, x, 500]
ListLinePlot[Table[{x, fp[x]}, {x, -10, 10, .25}], 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "f[x]"}]
ListLinePlot[Table[{x, Sin@fp[x]}, {x, -10, 10, .25}], 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "Sin[f[x]]"}]
```

You can verify that fp is good by checking the error at a given $x$ for example when $x=5$ we have the error `g[5, fp[5]] - fp[5]` which is a very small number: `1.40502*10^-10`. Increase the iterations if you want it smaller.

[image: fixed point fx]

[image: fixed point sin fx]

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to handle the symbolic dependence on $c$ and $b$

```
Clear[f, x, b, c]
f[x, 0] = x;
f[x_, k_] := f[x, k] = c Cos[2 f[x, k - 1]] + b x
f[x, 3]

n = 500;
c = 1/2;
b = 1.1;
fn = f[x, n];
Plot[fn, {x, -10, 10}]
Plot[Sin[fn], {x, -10, 10}]
```